# aspectj pointcut matching a specific annotation parameter value

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to define a pointcut around a method annotated with a custom annotation. The annotation has one parameter that I would like to include a check in the pointcut definition.

This is the annotation:

```
public @interface MyAnno {
  String[] types;
}
```

An example of how the annotation could be applied:

```
public class MyClass {
  @MyAnno(types={"type1", "type2"})
  public void doSomething() {
    // ...
  }
  @MyAnno(types={"type3"})
  public void doSomethingElse() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now I would like to have two pointcut definitions which select those two methods, based on the contents of the annotation.

Creating a pointcut on the annotation itself is relatively easy:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(myAnno)")
public void pointcutAnno(MyAnno myAnno) {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && pointcutAnno(myAnno)")
public void pointcut(MyAnno myAnno) {
}
```

This will match every occurrence of the of @MyAnno. But how can I define two pointcuts, one matching `@MyAnno` with `types` containing `"type1"` and the other matching `@MyAnno` with `types` containing `"type3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently AspectJ supports annotation value matching for a subset of the allowed kinds of annotation value.  Unfortunately the array type you are using is not supported (class isn't supported either). This feature is documented in the 1.6.0 AspectJ README (https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-160.html). There is a section on 'Annotation value matching'. As described there the syntax is actually quite intuitive for the basic cases:

```
enum TraceLevel { NONE, LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3 }

@interface Trace {
  TraceLevel value() default TraceLevel.LEVEL1;
}

aspect X {
  // Advise all methods marked @Trace except those with a tracelevel of none
  before(): execution(@Trace !@Trace(TraceLevel.NONE) * *(..)) {
    System.err.println("tracing "+thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

So just include the value you want to match on in the annotation. Unfortunately the array case is more complicated and so not implemented yet.  It needs a little more syntax to allow you to specify whether your pointcut means 'at least this in the array value' or 'exactly this and only this in the array value'. Presumably that would reuse `..` notation, something like this maybe:

```
execution(@MyAnno(types={"type1"}) * *(..)) { // exactly and only 'type1'
execution(@MyAnno(types={"type1",..}) * *(..)) { // at least 'type1'
```

Without the language support I'm afraid you do have to programmatically dig through the annotation in your code to check if it matches your constraint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Ideas. That helps me a lot! I was hoping that I didn't see the way to do the array matching. Well, runtime checks are required then. But in any way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with conditional pointcuts but those will involve a runtime test on the annotation attribute.

Native aspect syntax:

```
pointcut p(MyAnno myAnno): execution(* *(..)) 
    && @annotation(myAnno) 
    && if(Arrays.stream(myAnno.types()).anyMatch("type1"::equals));
```

Annotation based aspect syntax:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(myAnno) && if()")
public boolean pointcut(MyAnno myAnno) {
    return !Arrays.stream(myAnno.types()).anyMatch("type1"::equals);
}
```

Don't forget to import `java.util.Arrays` for both examples.

Currently, as of AspectJ version 1.8.13, you cannot statically restrict pointcut expressions on array typed annotation attributes as you would be able with non-array typed attributes, so this solution will involve a runtime test instead.

Comment: Thank you, too! I'd like to mark two commens as the solutions, but unfortunately Stackoverflow wouldn't let me. Your way of solving this issue helps me alot!